# I have some record in mysql database .I want to export daily record in csv file format using php?

Tags: php, mysql

**this is how i use mysql to get CSV export.If you have better code then suggest me**

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) ) {
$line = '';
foreach( $row as $value ) {
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) ){
          $value = ",";
     }
    else {
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
         $value = '"' . $value . '"' . ",";
    }
     $line .= $value;
 }
$data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );
$date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
}

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header( "Content-disposition: filename=".$file_name.".csv");
print "$header\n$data";
exit;
?>
```

Please give me the solution

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a fputcsv function you can use for these purposes:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: How i use it do not know .Please guide me